# ngrx EntityState.ids.includes() expects parameter with type never

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, angular-state-managmement, createentityadapter

I have an Ionic Angular project with ngrx State management. Here is my State definition:

```
export interface State {
  loaded: boolean;
  loading: boolean;
  invoices: InvoicesState;
  invoicePositions: InvoicePositionsState;
  selectedInvoice: InvoiceModel;
  availableTasks: AvailableTasksModel;
  nextPageUrl: string;
  invoicesFilter: string;
  comments: InvoiceCommentsState;
  selectedComment: CommentModel;
}

export interface InvoicesState extends EntityState<InvoicePreviewModel>{}

export const adapterInvoices: EntityAdapter<InvoicePreviewModel> = createEntityAdapter<InvoicePreviewModel>({
  selectId: (invoice: InvoicePreviewModel) => invoice.id,
  sortComparer: false,
});
```

...

```
export const initialState: State = {
  loaded: false,
  loading: false,
  invoices: adapterInvoices.getInitialState({}),
  invoicePositions: adapterInvoicePositions.getInitialState({}),
  selectedInvoice: null,
  availableTasks: null,
  nextPageUrl: null,
  invoicesFilter: null,
  comments: adapterInvoiceComments.getInitialState({}),
  selectedComment: null,
};
```

I want to make some changes to state when couple of specific conditions are met. Firstly I need to check if entity with specific id is stored in `EntityState`.

here is the code inside reducer where error occurs:

```
  on(InvoicesActions.stateTransitionSuccess, (state, { invoice, invoicePreview }) => {
    let invoices: InvoicesState;

    if (state.invoices.ids.includes(invoicePreview.id)) {
      invoices = adapterInvoices.updateOne({
        id: invoicePreview.id,
        changes: invoicePreview
      }, state.invoices);
    } else {
      // tbd
      // more conditions and logic

    }

    return {
      ...state,
      loaded: true,
      loading: false,
      selectedInvoice: invoice,
      invoices
    }
  }),
```

`includes()` function expects a `never` type parameter for some reason and I don't understand why. Here is the error that I get:

```
Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
```

[image: error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happened because the `ids` type is `number[] | string[]`, so you need to cast it to a numbers array `number[]` before using it, or you can use `some` instead of `includes` directly like the following:

```js
if (state.invoices.ids.some((id) => id === invoicePreview.id))
```